# Why does adding a C wire for a thermostat blow the fuse?

Tags: wiring, thermostat

I am adding a WiFi thermostat. I have R,W,G,Y wires. Plus 2 extra coming from upstairs that go between humidifier and humidistat. So I ran an extra wire for the C wire. When I attach it to the C terminal on circuit board, it blows the 5 amp onboard fuse. The white wire that is already attached to the C terminal and the red wire on the G terminal go to the outside A/C unit. Could those cause a short when adding the new wire? I have a tester but not sure what to check. It could be a bad thermostat. How do I test for a short on the thermostat terminals?

Here are some images without the new wire connected:

[image: circuit board]
[image: wiring diagram]
[image: circuit board]
[image: showing transformer]
[image: Thermostat wiring]

Comment: What's the volt-ampere rating on the transformer? Does the humidifier have its own transformer, or is it powered by the furnace transformer? Is the `C` wire attached to the thermostat when the fuse blows?

Comment: The red wire for the A/C unit is attached to the `Y` terminal, as it should be. That wire will lead to the coil of the contactor, and the white wire will return from the contactor coil. So when `Y` is energized, power flows through the contactor coil. There should be no problem there.

Comment: I added a pic of the transforme. Looks like 40 V A.  I don't see another transformer. I did more testing. I get about 27V between the C and R wires when both hooked up. But as soon as I attach the thermostat to the base plate, the fuse blows. Bad thermostat?

Comment: When you attach the thermostat, is it calling for heat/cool, or is it in standby? What is the make and model of the thermostat?

Comment: It is in standby. Emerson Sensi.

Comment: It was set for heat but I don't think it would've turned on (due to the temp setting) when I attached it. I probably should try that again. And buy more fuses.

Answer (score 1):

this turned out to be a bad thermostat. The manufacturer sent me a new one and it works great with the C wire attached.  One test they had me do was attach just the C and R wires. When I attached the old thermostat, the fuse blew.